# PS script stops after first else statement

Tags: powershell

Trying to start multiple processes all at once, but the script fails after my first 'else' statement. I tried doing a try/catch over the entire thing to get errors, but it still fails on my test machine since Slack isn't installed. Should I be using something else to get this to run all the lines non-stop? Or should this be re-organized to test paths first and then proceed based on that?

```
$Dropbox = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -Query "select * from sms_installedsoftware" | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -like "Dropbo*"}
$Dropboxapp = $app.installedlocation
$Slack = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -Query "select * from sms_installedsoftware" | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -like "Slack*"}
$SlackApp = $slack.installedlocation
$Office = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -Query "select * from sms_installedsoftware" | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -like "Office*"}
$OfficeApp = $Office.installedlocation



Start-Process "Chrome.exe" "www.google.com"
if ($SlackApp){
    start-process $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\slack\slack.exe} 
        else 
            {write-host "Please Install Slack"}

if ($Dropboxapp){
    start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dropbox\Client\dropbox.exe"} 
        else 
            {write-host "Dropbox does not appear to be installed"}

if ($OfficeApp){
    Start-Process Outlook.exe}
        Else
            {write-host "Office appears to be uninstalled or damaged"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the second if block isn't firing because the second line of code should read:

```
$Dropboxapp = $$Dropbox.installedlocation
```

I have a feeling the 3rd If block doesn't fire because the query is wrong.  Office might be something like "Microsoft Office..."  So change to something like:

```
$Office = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -Query "select * from sms_installedsoftware" | Where-Object {$_.ProductName -like "*Office*"}
```

Notice the extra "*"  My concern is `"Microsoft Office"` won't match `"Office*"` but it will match `"*Office*"`

Also it's a good practice to move filtering left.  Usually this is for performance though in this case that's not a problem.  Would look something like:

```
$Office = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -Query "SELECT * FROM sms_installedsoftware WHERE ProductName LIKE '%Office%'"
```

Let me know if this helps.  Thanks.

Comment: The * is required for selection in the SMS_Installedsoftware, you're first note is 100% true. I had the wrong variable from earlier when the script was only going to do one program. This fixed it :) 

Office variable works great, I don't much care what product is installed so it's very open ended.

Comment: I meant I added an extra "*" I modified the answer to reflect that.  Also typically you want to move filtering as far left as possible.  With WMI you can Spec a WQL query, so I added that example too.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the 'if' conditionals, or try one at a time and comment out others.  Also maybe put some logging in between things to see execution.  More likely this is a problem with logic tests of individual statements, rather than cadence or flow.

HTH

Comment: I removing the debugging in this to make it shorter. It makes it through just fine, but assigns 'yes' to every value, even though I type in 'no' in the parameter prompt